# Iterating over a dict object that contains nested elements

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

Python 5.6

Here is the result from a call using the geocoder module

```
import geocoder
anaddress = 'State Street, Hood River, OR'
g = geocoder.arcgis(anaddress)
d = g.geojson
print(d)
{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-121.52181774656506, 45.707876183969184]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties':
 {'provider': 'arcgis', 'ok': True, 'location': '1037 State St, Hood River, OR', 'lat': 45.707876183969184, 'lng': -121.52
181774656506, 'bbox': [-121.52281774656507, 45.706876183969186, -121.52081774656506, 45.70887618396918], 'encoding': 'utf-
8', 'status': 'OK', 'address': '1037 State St, Hood River, Oregon, 97031', 'status_code': 200, 'confidence': 9}, 'bbox': [
-121.52281774656507, 45.706876183969186, -121.52081774656506, 45.70887618396918]}
```

How can I iterate through this structure and print it out nicely?

Comment: `from pprint import pprint; pprint(d)`

Comment: 5.6?? Maybe 3.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your goal, only to the print the structure or to parse it as well?

In case you want to just print your output nicely, try this

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
```

This shall provide you with a nicely printed structure.
In order to parse this, you can do it as you would with any dictionary object using keys and values.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted!